# Angular 4 + ng2-datetime jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-cli

Does anybody have luck using ng2-datetime package with ng4? I am running into a jQuery issue as follows:

```
ERROR in /Users/markoffden/Sites/ato-card-front/node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime.ts (175,27): Cannot find name 'jQuery'.
/Users/markoffden/Sites/ato-card-front/node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime.ts (176,37): Cannot find name '$'.
/Users/markoffden/Sites/ato-card-front/node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime.ts (192,19): Cannot find name '$'.
/Users/markoffden/Sites/ato-card-front/node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime.ts (196,27): Cannot find name 'jQuery'.
/Users/markoffden/Sites/ato-card-front/node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime.ts (197,37): Cannot find name '$'.
/Users/markoffden/Sites/ato-card-front/node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime.ts (224,19): Cannot find name '$'.
```

Though I have followed all the accepted fixes for this around the web, such as:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

and including:

```
"types": ["jquery"]
```

in my `tsconfig.json`, but still get this error.

I am using CLI.

**UPD**
And my `angular-cli.json` is

```
///...

"styles": [
    "../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css",
    "../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "sass/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
    "../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "../bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js",
    "../bower_components/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"
]

///...
```

Comment: use this `declare var $: any;` in your component, where you are using jquery

Comment: unfortunatelly, it does not help

Comment: `declare var jQuery: any;` use this also

Comment: did you add jquery in `angular-cli.json` under scripts?

Comment: Generally a poor idea using jQuery with Angular. They're not meant for each other.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz yes, but are there any other options for datepicker?

Comment: Just google for "angular 2 datepicker" and you will get some options. I usually go with PrimeNG's calendar module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [ngx-datepiker](https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker) is the best option for now. Switched to this lib.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The only solution I was able to find is below.

**step 1:** Install jQuery and types

`npm install jquery --save`

`npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

**step 2:** Add the library to the scripts in *.angular-cli.json*

`"scripts": [
    "../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]`

**step 3: Add:** `/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />` to the top of the ***src/typeings.d.ts*** file.

I tried using [angular's approach for adding 3rd party libs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib) first with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

if you use angular-cli, add in typings.d.ts this:

```
declare var $: any;

declare var jQuery: any;
```